# Django -- hide links from certain users

Tags: django, user-interface, permissions

Is it possible, on a Django webapp, to hide certain links from those users who do not have the permission to click the link?

I bet there is a per-link way to check if the user has persmission to click the link, and then show the link (or not) based on that test. However, when there are a lot links spread across a whole bunch of web pages, that can be ridiculously tedious. Are there any ways to achieve this across the whole website with a setting or something?

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: Nooooooooooo.

Comment: Well, thanks for the response. I would have thought this would be a feature -- perhaps in future Django releases...

Comment: @zengr -- agreed! I'm not sure why I was downvoted. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write a template tag similar to [`spaceless`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#spaceless) that goes over its contents and removes all links that are not accessible. this would save you from having to touch each link manually.

Comment: Interesting, I'll look into that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to write a custom template tag that would accept a link url, reverse it, introspect what permissions were required for the target view, and then conditionally display it.

You'd still have to touch every link in every template that you wanted to make fancy like that, and it would probably be an ugly beast.  All in all, it's probably easier if you come up with a more centralized way to control access.

Comment: Ya, I had considered that approach. But, as you pointed out, I would still have to do something to every link in every template. As it is now, I am just using the default authorization setup standard with Django. I just thought it would be aesthetically pleasing for the user to only see links they can actually use. Not really a functionality issue, really.